# Laravel Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' PHP 8.1.6 Laravel 9.14.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I cant connect to my Laravel (MySQL) database, it is a local dev no docker or hosting.

error : `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

I have tested it both with and without passwords, after each test I stop the server and make sure I run `php artisan config:clear`

.env (
i have tested it with no quotes at all, single quotes and double quotes with no success)

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME='root'
DB_PASSWORD=""
```

database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

code added for testing (this is only here so i can quickly test login details)

```
<?php
            $servername = "127.0.0.1";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";

            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }
            echo "Connected successfully";
        ?>
```

`extension=pdo_mysql` is enabled in my php.ini and seems to be my only php.ini file

Comment: on your `.env` try `DB_USERNAME=root` (without `'`) & `DB_PASSWORD=` (without the `""`)

Comment: i have tested it with no quotes at all, single quotes and double quotes with no success

Comment: Run `php artisan serve` after configure `.env`, not before.

Comment: are you able to login on 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin with the same credentials?
you can try to replace 127.0.0.1 to localhost

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all, Laravel can't connect to a DB.  Check priveleges and make sure the DB exists. Also try to connect with login and password using MySQL Workbench. You can see if it is working that you don't have a problem or you have some problem it is not Laravel problem.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html